# In Auction house can we still select item based on gold radius?

Tags: diablo-iii

I used to be able to find those.

I don't exactly remember the exact stats name. Gold radius, increase gold radius, or what.

Now I can't find it anymore since the latest patch. Can people confirm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribute is called "pickup radius".

Comment: Is it still there?

Comment: Try picking up large amounts of gold without at least one of these...very inefficient

Comment: 1) Several witchdoctor skills scale off of pickup radius. 2) Melee classes that are tank speced can have issues picking up health globes without at least some pickup radius.